# Comparar fechas con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

En la base de datos se guardan las fechas así "2019-04-30 09:16:16" y necesito realizar una búsqueda con solo la fecha "2019-04-30"

¿cómo hago para comparar ese tipo de búsqueda?

Comment: utilizar like en tu consulta no te serviría? tipo `select fecha from tabla where fecha like fecha%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que se observa en tu pregunta, tu guardas un registro de tipo `DATETIME` ya que tienes también hora, minuto y segundo.

Entonces como estas trabajando en MySQL, este mismo posee una función llamada `DATE()` que de acuerdo a la documentación extrae la parte de fecha de un campo de tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`

**EJEMPLO**

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE DATE(fecha1) = DATE(fecha2);
```

> Lo que se hizo fue pasar adentro de la función `DATE` tanto la columna
>   que comparada como aquel valor contra el cual va a ser comparado, para
>   que de este modo los valores que son tomados en cuenta solo sean
>   `YYYY-MM-DD` ignorando lo demás.

REFERENCIAS:

- Enlace oficial a la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es convertir tus fecha a date con la funcion convert en tu consulta sql

ejemplo:

```
SELECT * from table where CONVERT(fechaEnTuTabla, DATE)=CONVERT("2019-04-30", DATE)
```

espero que sea util.

desde php puedes compararlos convirtiendolos a date ejemplo:

```
if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2019-04-30"))==date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha)))
```